# Fetch each client data and send it to email

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I, My stack on something and really seems not get better.
Is it possible to have a script that fetch individually each client row data and send it to their email address? 
Still trying but I can't find answer.

Anyone with great suggestions?

here is my code:

```
                            <?php
                            $sqlSelect = "SELECT 
                                                    cl.client_name,
                                                    DATE(jb.date),
                                                    jb.job_number,
                                                    jb.repair,
                                                    st.site_name
                                            FROM
                                                        job_cards jb
                                            INNER JOIN
                                                        clients cl ON (cl.client_id = jb.client_id)
                                            LEFT JOIN
                                                        sites st on (st.site_id = jb.site_id)
                                            WHERE
                                                        jb.completed =  1 
                                            AND cl.client_id = jb.client_id

                                            ORDER BY cl.client_name ASC";



                                $tresult = mysql_query($sqlSelect);


                                while($userData = mysql_fetch_assoc($tresult))
                                {
                                    if($i%2==0)
                                        $classname = 'evenRow';
                                    else if($i%2==1)


                                ?>


                                        <tr class='<?php if(isset($classname)) echo $classname;?>'>


<td width=250>                                  
    <?php 
    //echo $userData['client_name)']; 

    echo mysql_real_escape_string ($userData['client_name]); ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width=100>
    <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string ($userData['DATE(jb.date)']); ?>
    </td>
    <td width=50>
     <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string($userData['job_number']);?>
    </td>
    <td>
     <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string($userData['site_name']);?>
    </td>
    <td>
     <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string($userData['repair']);?>
    </td>

                                        <?php 

                                    $to .= "realconcept@usa.com";
                                    $subject ="Monthly Reports for company";

                                    $headers .='MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                                    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
                                    $headers .= 'From: System Admin <mike@guardre.com>' . "\r\n";//<noreply@example.com>'


                                            $message .="
                                            Company Name : ".$userData['client_name']."\n".
                                            "Date : ".$userData['DATE(jb.date)']."\n".
                                            "Site : ".$userData['site_name']."\n".
                                            "Description : ".$userData['repair']."\n";

                                            if(mail('realconcept@usa.com', $subject, $message, $header))


                                    $i++;
                                }
                                    ?>
```

**What is wrong with my code?**s

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question. What I see is that you have a table with clients data. Is that right? And... you want to send that table to multiple email addresses?

Comment: The Table Data Display A list of Client_IDs with many things. What I 'm asking is that when the table is loaded, IS IT Possible to FETCH Single Client Information? link, Client_ID 1, send to client1@email.com; client_ID 2 send to client2@email.com; etc......

Comment: Ok, let's do something first. Can you please take some minutes to format and indent your code properly so I can read it better. Then we'll continue to the answer. ok? let me know when you're done formatting the code :)

Comment: Yes, I have the Table format [HERE](http://kopanang.co.za/monthreport.php) please check it

Comment: I think you should update the question, it's quite hard to understand. I see the table and the data it contains. What do you want to do with it? I didn't understand if you wanted to send it by mail or what. And still have to fix the code presentation :P

Comment: What I Need is simply to send each client data row to it's email address. so if we have 300 client, I want to know if there is a code that automatically fetches each clients data and send it to their email address. Thant is what I'm asking

Comment: Perfect. I understood the question, now, can you format your code so I can know better what's wrong with your code? :)

Comment: Hi Juan, there is. I have edit and try to format my code. It's a simple php script. Pls have a look nd pls bring something new. Thanks alot